Public keys in web applications
I know that I am not supposed to place keys in my client sided application, such as a web application. But, there are more and more service providers (e.g. Google Maps, Amplitude SDK, etc) these days that are instructing us to place keys in our web application's JavaScript code.
How exactly do these providers ensure that no other developer is stealing my app key to be used in some other application while making me liable for their usage? I have seen some providers ask me to whitelist the site in which I plan to place my key. But how exactly do they guarantee that developers don't spoof this information in the request headers? Isn't that super easy? What other mitigation tactics do they use? I'm just confused how this has become a standard with some service providers. Seems like there should be an obvious answer here that I am unaware of

Are you talking about private keys or public keys? Your title mention "public keys", but your question body only say about "keys" in general.

I would really like to see the reference to Google saying to put private keys in JS. That's against their security stance in general.

I assume this question is about "API keys" which are from a security perspective not keys but tokens.

@Progman These are keys that applications ask you to insert so that they can identify you and bill you for your usage

@scrappedcola look at this for example https://www.docs.developers.amplitude.com/data/sdks/browser-2/#initialize-the-sdk

Yea that's just bad and their stance in the help center that ti's more of a public key is not in line with actual practices(https://community.amplitude.com/data-instrumentation-57/api-key-is-exposed-publicly-if-i-am-using-the-the-js-sdk-should-i-create-a-proxy-service-on-my-server-to-prevent-this-871).. I think it's a push of "just get things done" rather than actually caring about secuity and protecting their customers. I don't think I've seen this in Google's docs as they are pretty on top of security relating practices, which is why I asked to see the Google reference.
